# Does First() in LINQ cause eager or lazy loading?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a query:

```
db.Order.Include("OrderItem").First(r => r.Id == OrderId)
```

1. Does First() on it own cause Eager or Lazy loading?
2. If not then how would you force Eager loading for a First()?
3. Is the above combined query Eagerly or lazily loaded?

Comment: Linq to SQL or Linq to EF? Those are 2 extremely different frameworks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` are executed immediately (eager) at the point where they're called.

All standard LINQ operators, which return a single, non-enumerable result, and those that do not return an explicit `IEnumerable<T>`, are executed immediately.

See [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution#classification-table) for the complete list of LINQ operators.